# Namenode stuck in SAFEMODE after cluster restart

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, hdfs, high-availability

I have a setup of ***3 node Hadoop cluster***(**Apache Hadoop-2.8.0**). I have deployed **2 namenodes that are configured in HA mode using QJM**. 2 datanodes are configured on the same machine where namenode are installed. 3rd node is used for quorum purpose only.

```
Setup  
Node1 { nn1, dn1, jn1, zkfc1, zkServer1 }  
Node2 -> {nn2, dn2, jn2, zkfc2, zkServer2}  
Node3 -> {jn3,  zkServer3}
```

I stopped the cluster for some reason(power recycled the servers)  and since them I am not able to start the cluster successfully. After examining the logs I found that the namenodes are in safe mode and none of them are able to load the block in memory. Below is the status of namenode from namenode UI.

> Safe mode is ON. The reported blocks 0 needs additional 6132675 blocks
>   to reach the threshold 0.9990 of total blocks 6138814. The number of
>   live datanodes 0 has reached the minimum number 0. Safe mode will be
>   turned off automatically once the thresholds have been reached.
>   61,56,984 files and directories, 61,38,814 blocks = 1,22,95,798 total
>   filesystem object(s). Heap Memory used 5.6 GB of 7.12 GB Heap Memory.
>   Max Heap Memory is 13.33 GB. Non Heap Memory used 45.19 MB of 49.75 MB
>   Committed Non Heap Memory. Max Non Heap Memory is 130 MB.

There were numerous *JVM Pause* messages in name-node logs so I have tried increasing the HADOOP_HEAPSIZE, increasing the heap size in HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS but no success.

Need help..

Comment: have u tried this command :-     hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave
?

Comment: I have tried this. after forcefully leaving the safemode, all the blocks are marked corrupted by namenode. But all these blocks are good.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue after getting reply from hadoop users mailing list. 
The issue was due to block reports not getting generated by datanodes. I checked the logs and found that the datanode was complaining about **ipc.maximum.data.length** being smaller than required.

I added below property in core-site.xml file to solve the issue which worked for me.

```
<property>
     <name>ipc.maximum.data.length</name>
     <value>101372499</value>
 </property>
```